# Protect a page from external access outside the server

Tags: javascript, php

In a backend panel, in order to populate a datatable, I echo the records in a php page in format JSON, then I parse, format and populate the datatable with JS.

The issue is, how do I prevent peoples from accessing that php page and leaking all the informations?

This is what my code look like:

```
    var options = {
        data: {
            type: 'remote',
            source: {
                read: {
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1/inc/phpscripts/printinfo.php',
                },
            },
            pageSize: 10,
            serverPaging: false,
            serverFiltering: false,
            serverSorting: false,
        },
        layout: {
            scroll: false,
            footer: false
        },
        sortable: true,
        pagination: true,
        columns: [{
            field: 'id',
            title: '#',
            sortable: false,
            width: 20,
            selector: {
                class: ''
            },
            textAlign: 'center',
        }, {
            field: 'name',
            title: 'name',
        }, {
            field: 'surname',
            title: 'surname',
        }, {
            field: 'address',
            title: 'address',
        }, {
            field: 'phone',
            title: 'phone',
        },
        }],
    };
```

This is the code of the printinfo.php

```
    function datatable($userid){
        global $conn;
        $total = totalrows($userid);
        $pagination = ceil($total/10);
        echo '{
        "meta": {
            "page": 1,
            "pages": '.$pagination.',
            "perpage": 10,
            "total": '.$total.',
            "sort": "desc",
            "field": "name"
        },
        "data":';
        $rows = array();
        $query = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ? ORDER BY name DESC');
        $query->bind_param('i', $userid);
        if (!$query->execute());
        $res = $query->get_result();
        $counter = 0;
        //$rows = array();
        while ($data = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            $rows[] = $data;
        }
        print json_encode($rows);
        echo '}';
    }
    datatable(SESSION['id']);
```

While this is the display content of printinfo.php

```
{ "meta": { "page": 1, "pages": 1, "perpage": 10, "total": 4, "sort": "desc", "field": "level" }, "data":
[{"id":1,"name":"frank","surname":"blank","address":"st andrew","phone":"+1555484845"},
{"id":1,"name":"andrew","surname":"blank","address":"st paroli","phone":"+1555895685"}]}
```

It works fine, but I don't think this is secure at all.

So, how would you approach it in order to secure the datas?

Comment: *how do I prevent peoples from accessing that php page and leaking all the informations?* require the user be authenticated

Comment: tip, dont build your json manually, replace them `echo '{...'` with an array then add $data to it i.e `$array['data'][] = $data`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the page only prints if the user is authenticated with sessions, but I would like to prevent anyone from displaying the page at all, because someone can hijack the session and leak all the informations. 
Do you think moving the php page in a sub-directory not accessible from browser can be a solution? But then how do I fetch the datas with JS?

Comment: you did not mention that lol. use ssl and http only session cookie then session hijacking is impossible

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Wait, no, I cannot do sessions, because the request to populate the datatable comes from the server itself in the listing page, not from the user, but the page does print the datas to whoever display it.

Comment: _“Wait, no, I cannot do sessions”_ - what are you talking about? The code you have shown us, already contains `datatable(SESSION['id'])` – so how did that work then, in your (alleged) “can’t use sessions” environment? And you specified the URL in the options for the datatable script that _runs on the client side_, so why are you saying the request came “from the server itself”?

Answer (score 1):

You should build some authentication scheme, in order to validate the identity of user that fetches your data.

A simple example (not secure at all, but shows the goal) - send some identification code as post request to that php script and validate it there.

Better security can be achieved by creating a database with hashed or encrypted passwords and validating the user at sign in stage. After that validation, you can store some credentials on the server and check in your php script the identity.

Again, this is not so simple as described and should be done carefully.